# Consultas aninhadas no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou começando no Laravel agora e estou com algumas dificuldades quando o assunto é "consultas".

Estou usando a ultima versão do Laravel que, se eu não me engano, é a 7.4.

Quando eu trabalhava com o PHP puro eu fazia minhas consultas, em casos específicos, assim:

```
$consultaCategoria = "SELECT * FROM categoria";
$objConsutaCategoria = mysqli_query($conexao, $consultaCategoria);
while($arrLinhaCategoria = mysqli_fetch_array($objConsutaCategoria, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    
    echo "<h2>{$arrLinhaCategoria['title']}</h2>";
    
    $consultaProduto = "SELECT * FROM produto where categoria_id = {$arrLinhaCategoria['id']}";
    $objConsutaProduto = mysqli_query($conexao, $consultaProduto);
    while($arrLinhaProduto = mysqli_fetch_array($objConsutaProduto, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        
        echo "<h2>{$arrLinhaProduto['title']}</h2>";
    
    }

}
```

Mais eu não sei como fazer essa estrutura no laravel.

Eu pensei em fazer assim direto na view:

```
@foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory)

   <h2> {{$subcategory->title}} </h2>

   @foreach ($products as $product)
      @if ($product->subcategory_id == $subcategory->id)
         
           <h2> {{$product->title}} </h2>

      @endif
   @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Só que assim eu trago uma carga muito grande de produtos na consulta. Imagine que tem 100 produtos, vou acabar trazendo os 100 produtos no foreach pra cada categoria.

Resumindo tudo, eu preciso listar todas as categorias junto a todos os seus produtos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, um produto pertence a uma subcategoria, certo? Dessa forma, uma subcategoria tem vários produtos, ou seja, uma relation [One to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). Dessa forma, você pode acessar os produtos que pertencem a sua subcategoria da seguinte forma:

```
@foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory)
   <h2> {{$subcategory->title}} </h2>
   @foreach ($subcategory->products as $product)
           <h2> {{$product->title}} </h2>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Caso a relation ainda não esteja definida, você poderá defini-lá igual ao que encontramos nos [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). No seu caso, o model **SubCategory.php** teria:

```
class Subcategory extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, chamando `$subcategory->products` retornaremos todos produtos pertencentes a subcategoria armazenada em `$subcategory`

Comment: Luca muito obrigado, conseguir entender como funciona graças a sua resposta, e conseguir implementar na minha aplicação. Muito obrigado